# How to write powershell catch error stacktrace to a listitem?

Tags: powershell

I am using a powershell script where I do some logic. It is a big powershell and is scheduled. I would like to triggered when there occurred some error. I would like to have the whole error stacktrace with the line number and all other detail info. How to do that?

```
try
{
    //some logic
}
catch
{
    "error occurred, write the error stacktrace to the loglist where I got an email alert for each new list item"

    $Error[0].Exception

    $webURL = "https://portal.myCompany.net/" 
    $listName = "Logging"

    $web = Get-SPWeb $webURL

    #Get the SPList object
    $list = $web.Lists[$listName]

    #Create a new item
    $newItem = $list.Items.Add()

    #Add properties to this list item
    $newItem["Title"] = $item["Title"]
    $newItem["Exception"] = $Error[0].Exception
    $newItem["srPortalUrlExtranet"] = $item["srPortalUrlExtranet"]
    $newItem["srPortalUrl"] = $item["srPortalUrl"]
    $newItem["srProjectName"] = $item["srProjectName"]

    #Update the object so it gets saved to the list
    $newItem.Update()
    $web.Dispose()

}
```

UPDATE:

When I print $_ I see this in the editor:

```
Exception calling "SelfServiceCreateSite" with "11" argument(s): "Another site already exists at https://portal.myCompany.net/projects/82611730. Delete th
is site before attempting to create a new site with the same URL, choose a new URL, or create a new inclusion at the path you originally specified."
At C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\CreateProjectSiteOriginal.ps1:174 char:54
+     $newSite = $webApp.Sites[0].SelfServiceCreateSite <<<< ($ProjectSiteUrl, $ProjectSiteName, $item["srProjectDescription"], 1033, "{F90E6CBE-49BE-4F78-A937
-191DD04BB5B3}#WTProjectSite", $Owner, "PortalSupport", "PortalSupport@mycompany.nl", $Owner, "PortalSupport", "PortalSupport@mycompany.nl") 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Like you see here, is the message and a little bit of the stackerror inclusive the line number.

When I print $_.Exception I see this:

```
Exception calling "SelfServiceCreateSite" with "11" argument(s): "Another site already exists at https://portal.myCompany.net/projects/82611730. Delete th
is site before attempting to create a new site with the same URL, choose a new URL, or create a new inclusion at the path you originally specified."
```

Here I missing the stackerror and the line number.

When I print $_.Exception.Message I see:

```
Exception calling "SelfServiceCreateSite" with "11" argument(s): "Another site already exists at https://portal.mycompany.net/projects/82611730. Delete th
is site before attempting to create a new site with the same URL, choose a new URL, or create a new inclusion at the path you originally specified."
```

Here I missing the stackerror and the line number.

When I print $_.Exception.Stacktrace I see:

```
  at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.AuxiliaryMethodInvoke(Object target, Object[] arguments, MethodInformation methodInformation, Object[] origina
lArguments)
   at System.Management.Automation.ParserOps.CallMethod(Token token, Object target, String methodName, Object[] paramArray, Boolean callStatic, Object valueToS
et)
   at System.Management.Automation.MethodCallNode.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Object value)
   at System.Management.Automation.MethodCallNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.AssignmentStatementNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ExecutionContext context)
   at System.Management.Automation.StatementListNode.ExecuteStatement(ParseTreeNode statement, Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionCo
ntext context)
```

This is another stackerror than I see in my fist print. I would like to have the stackerror like my first print. Also here I am missing the linenumber.

How can I get the message, stacktrace and linenumber from the exception?

Answer (score 1):

There are two type of exceptions in PowerShell

1. Terminating - A serious error during execution that halts the command (or script execution) completely.
2. Non-Terminating - A non-serious error that allows execution to continue despite the failure.

If a you use a global `try..catch` then Non-terminating errors must have error action preference set to Stop to be caught. In case of Terminating errors, execution will stop and `catch` block will never get executed.

I would suggest you handle each statement in the script separately and then handle `cmdlets` which can fails using `ErrorAction` parameter.

- [An Introduction to Error Handling in PowerShell](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell.aspx)

Comment: This solved my issue of `Set-PnPListItem` exceptions not being captured in a try...catch block, i.e. `Set-PnPListItem -Identity $ID -List $listTitle -Values @{$field=$updVal} -UpdateType UpdateOverwriteVersion -ErrorAction Stop`

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the `catch` block, the error that was just thrown is represented by `$_`, so you don't need to use `$Error[0]`.

`$_.Exception` is a `System.Exception` object, so you can access

```
$_.Exception.Message
$_.Exception.StackTrace
```

[`System.Exception` properites](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.systemexception_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)

UPDATE:

The `$_` error itself is a `System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord` object.  Maybe the information you are looking for can be found in the properites:

```
$_.ErrorDetails
$_.ScriptStackTrace
```

Here is a link to the MSDN documentation on the [`ErrorRecord`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.errorrecord_members(v=vs.85).aspx) class.

Comment: see my update please..